# What is the equivalent querydsl code for the below Native sql query(Sybase)?

Tags: spring-boot, datetime, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

```sql
select d.drvr_id, z.reg_id , convert(varchar,d.arrival_dt,100),0 as DrvrCount 
from driverTable d,reg_zip z where d.model_flag=1
```

arrival_dt is a Timestamp.

I have tried the below code.In my repository file. Getting some compilations. Please suggest me an approach. I want to convert the timestamp object to date string.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Tuple> GetDrivers() {

        QRegZipModel regZip = QRegZipModel.regZipModel;
        QDriverModel driverModel = QDriverModel.driverModel;
        JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
        //Expression<String> dateExpr = Expressions.stringTemplate(String.class,"convert(varchar, {0}, 100)", driverModel.arrival_dt);
        //NumberPath<Integer> dummy = Expressions.numberPath(Integer.class, "dummy");
        //String dateAlias = "MM/dd/yyyy"; 
        List<Tuple> driversList = null;
        driversList = queryFactory.select(driverModel.drvr_id, regZip.reg_id ,SQLExpressions.date(driverModel.arrival_dt)
        ,count(0) as DrvrCount
                ).from(driverModel, regZip)
                .where(driverModel.model_flag.eq(true))
                .createQuery().getResultList();

        return driversList;
    }
```

Comment: are you saying the `arrival_dt` column is of **type** `timestamp`? or is the column of type `date`/`datetime`/`smalldatetime`? what error ('compilations'?) are you receiving?

Comment: arrival_dt is also variable in my entity model class which is of type Timestamp and it is a column in my sybase db of type TIMESTAMP. "The method count(int) is not defined" is the error I've been getting. But on commenting out the count(0) as DrvrCount line I'm able to compile but getting runtime exceptions which is because of "SQLExpressions.date(driverModel.arrival_dt)" I'm unable to find any equivalent code for converting timestamp column to Date(format 100 in Sybase) as String type.